# Splitting cell into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, csv, erd

I have a CSV file of 1000 movies and their corresponding genres, most movies have more than one genre and as part of normalisation process I would have to split the genre cells so that it has only one genre in each cell.

The picture depicted below best explains what I'm talking about and I want to achieve.

Is there an efficient method to duplicate the `movieID` cell depending on the number of genres and split the genres into those cells, instead of manually doing it?

For example, movie1 has 3 Genres: `Drama,Romance,Thriller`. What I want to achieve is: 3 cells of "movie1" and the corresponding genres: `Drama`, `Romance`, `Thriller`.

[image: MovieID and Genre]

[image: Database ERD]

Answer (score 0):

You should create 3 tables. One for the movies, one for the genres and one for the lookup between movie and genres.

```
CREATE TABLE movies
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    ... whatever else you need ...;

CREATE TABLE genres
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    ... whatever else you need ...;

CREATE TABLE movie_genre
    movie_id INT,
    genre_id INT;
```

For your example the tables will contain:

```
INSERT INTO movies (id, name) VALUES (1, 'movie1');

INSERT INTO genres(id, name) VALUS (1, 'Drama'),(2, 'Romance'),(3, 'Thriller');

INSERT INTO movie_genre (movie_id, genre_id) VALUES (1, 1),(1,2),(1,3);
```

I have added a working fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dfd42/1

Comment: I already created those 3 tables, I have attached a picture of my ERD, but my concern is when it comes to inserting data into the tables.

Comment: I have already inserted data into my 'Movies' and 'Genres' table, but my concern is the 'Movie_Genre' table.

Comment: If you insert you have to create the genres table first of course. then you insert a movie, fetch his id (last insert id) and add the rows to the movie_genre table. Of course this is a little bit more complicated then writing just one row in the movie table but you will have much more flexibility afterwards in fetching data. Normally you only insert once and read often. So its a question of priorities

Comment: Even I don't know much about movies, but maybe they have their own unique id like books have. So you can use this id in your table. so you know the id right before inserting. That saves the step of requesting the id after insert.